# how to add watch os 2 extension in cordova iPhone app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos

I added `watch extension` to `cordova` project it runs very well in `simulator`. But when i try to run app in `apple watch` it shows me linker error[image]

even i tried [this watch plugin](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch)
and [this watch plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AppleWatch)
still no luck

> Anyone knows the whole procedure to add `watch extension` to `cordova` project

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.1 watch os 2,iOS 9.1,Cordova 5.4.1,cordova-ios@3.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I resolve all issue and its work well for me even create ipa for it so following are the steps

1. when I add watch os target and try to archive got linker error of (libCordova.a not found or AVFoundation framework not found) to resolve it remove everything from

> Build setting -> Other Linker Flags *in watch app and watch extension target*

Warning! - Do not touch Other Linker Flags of iOS(cordova) app
[image]

2. If you try to archive it again new error will arise
   [image: cordova file not found]
   to resolve it add this

> $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include

line in all 3 targets in following path

> Build Settings -> Header Search paths

[image]

3. then i got error on version string
   [image]

resolve it by giving same Bundle version String, Short & Bundle Version to all 3 targets from info.plist

[image]

4. Hell Yeah! all error are gone now I can create ipa or run it to paired apple watch ruthlessly